# Why office apps doesn't open in web browser in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

I've installed Microsoft office web apps offline in the VM and also Installed SharePoint 2016 in another VM machine. Both VMs are connected to the domain. Besides, I've successfully connected SharePoint to the office farm. But when I try to open docx files or any office apps on the web browser I get this error :
[image: Error While opening office apps]
Which step I've made mistake ??

Comment: are you sure your MS Word Client app works properly ?

Comment: AIMEN BOULAHIA , yes I'm sure . Is there any way to check it ??

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `Minimal Download Strategy` feature is what is causing this behavior, thus I would advise deactivating it as the following:

- Go to Site settings
- Manage site features
- Deactivate Minimal download Strategy.

Otherwise, you have to review the [Office Online Server configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server) and browser settings.